# SQL Performance Results

Tags: sql

if we get data from code through sql using select query and same query is executed on sql view, then which way is faster from performance point. mean view's display data faster or direct sql query that we run on tables fetch the data faster?

Comment: Neither. Both execute at the sql core at the fastest possible speed (usually the same time each run) and you can use 'execution plan' in SSMS and break down of what the query did in 'milliseconds' - I would think the view is slower because it needs to update the GUI, where as programatically, once the result is in local memory; populating a dataset is instant without any event updates. even in hundreds of megabytes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot answer such a generally asked question. Views *can* be faster, but don't have to be. It highly depends on the DBMS you are using, on the view you created, on the amount of data you have loaded, on the indexes you created and on the queries you run against the table/view.

Comment: if i say the query is simple like select * from customer where customer names like %A%. then which fetch data faster. view's or the code that using the above query ?

Comment: Both have to do a full table scan. But, however, some DBMS provide a feature called „materialized views.“ When you create a materialized view with the above query, you can precalculate the result set and so a select on such a view would be faster.

Comment: If you are using wildcards as the first charcter in a like clause, then you willnot get good performanc eno matter waht. It is an indicatior of poor design if you are using those types of queries. They are a SQL Antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is faster.  A view is just a stored query, so if they are structured the same they should execute in the same timeframe.  If you look at the execution plan for the plain SQL or the view execute, they should be identical if the SQL in both is identical.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of factors could affect this. Is the view an indexed view? It could be faster. Is the view a view that calls other views that calls other views? It will probably be significantly slower than directly hitting that tables (especially if the view chain is long and complicated). In looking at performance, the particular query and the particular hardware set-up will dictate which is faster. You need to try both ways to see.